# Do VmPeak & VmHWM have any measurement periods?

Tags: rhel, proc, virtual-memory

While reading kernel documentation I came across VmPeak & VmHWM, and it's a bit unclear to me.  VmPeak in `/proc/<pid>/status` is described to be peak virtual memory size. Peak for what period?

Is this period the same for VmHWM, aka peak resident set size ("high water mark")?

Comment: Might be of interest: http://locklessinc.com/articles/memory_usage/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for `proc` I would be inclined to interpret these 2 parameters as over the lifetime of the process, so to answer your question I would say no there is no time period associated. Especially given they use the term "high water mark".

```
* VmPeak: Peak virtual memory size.
* VmHWM: Peak resident set size ("high water mark").
```

As further evidence I'd also cite this article, titled: [Understanding and optimizing Memory utilization](http://web.archive.org/web/20171209130457/http://careers.directi.com/display/tu/Understanding+and+optimizing+Memory+utilization).

> Note that the VmHWM parameter is interesting inasmuch as it signifies the amount of physical memory required for the process at peak times.

Comment: Note that the process could write to /proc/<pid>/clear_refs to reset VmHWM. I'm not sure of a use case in the wild or if this works for VmPeak.